# Corte entre secciones CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, web, responsive

Hola a todos estoy intentando crear este corte entre secciones con css pero no consigo lograrlo, agradecería cualquier ayuda o idea para solucionar esto.
Son dos secciones con imágenes como fondo y en medio de ellas tengo esta cuña con un borde solido.

[image: corte entre secciones]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar con CSS la propiedad skew para darle la inclinación que deseas tanto a un lado como a otro con dos divs, por ejemplo colocados uno al lado de otro ocupando cada uno el 50% de la pantalla. Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrían ser las clases de CSS:

```
  .izq  {
          width: 50%;
          height: 10px;
          background-color: grey;
         -ms-transform: skewY(20deg); /* IE 9 */
         -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
         transform: skewY(20d20deg);
    }

    .drc  {
           width: 50%;
           height: 10px;
           background-color: grey;
           -ms-transform: skewY(-20deg); /* IE 9 */
          -webkit-transform: skewY(-20deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
          transform: skewY(-20d20deg);
     }
```

Además te dejo aquí un enlace que te puede ayudar a comprender cómo se usa esta propiedad y otras que tal vez te sean de utilidad: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido para solucionar tu duda por favor márcala como correcta para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema sepa que esa solución funciona. Gracias.